# I can't use olympics.csv on my jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

To see the file and do some operations from `opympics.csv` file, I wrote:

```
!cat olympics.csv
```

Then,the output is :

> cat: olympics.csv: No such file or directory

How can I use this and do some operations as I'm using **ubuntu** OS?

Comment: provide the *absolute* path to your `olympics.csv`, e.g. `!cat /home/your-username/Downloads`. Or put the file in the same folder with the notebook file.

Comment: Do i need to download the cat or  csv file? If though,plz tell me the way

Comment: Where is the file currently? The error clearly shows that the notebook and the file are not in the same directory. Can you see which directory is your notebook and the `olympics.csv` file in your machine?

Comment: Also, you are stating that you do some operations in `opympics.csv` but your cat code is referring to `olympics.csv`

Comment: Ow! I got that, Just
1) Downloaded the 'olympics.csv'  
2) kept that on the same directory where I'd installed the jupyter notebook. 
3) Command run of the Jupyter notebook, successful output.